# How can a React Native client to know the GetStream.io Feed is empty?

Tags: getstream-io

We have a React Native client that is using the Feed product from GetStream.io.  What is the best way to detect the feed is empty so that I can display an empty state graphic.

I did not see the ability to add an empty state graphic to the getStream.io Feed component but if that already exists please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#flatfeed

You can use the `setListRef` and watch the field `parentProps.data` (you will have to looking for it I don't remember where it is).